# Is calling close() on object returned by MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Object) is mandatory?

Tags: java, mockito

I would like is it mandatory to call close() on object returned by MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Object)? If answer is yes, why do I need to call it?
Assume we have such an example:

```
public class MockitoAnnotationsOpenMocksTest {
@Mock
private Foo var;
@BeforeMethod
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void foo() {
    Mockito.when(var.name()).thenReturn("foo");
    System.out.println("test foo" + ", var name " + var.name());
}
@Test
public void foo2() {
    System.out.println("test foo2" + ", var name " + var.name());

}
private class Foo {
    String name() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

}

running it with testng result is:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
test foo, var name foo
test foo2, var name null
PASSED: foo
PASSED: foo2
PASSED: foo2
```

AFAIK in every call of @BeforeMethod MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this); initializes var object one more time, so I do not see any sense to use close() method after every test method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) says:

> If static method mocks are used, it is required to close the initialization. Additionally, if using third-party mock-makers, other life-cycles might be handled by the open-release routine.

So no, tests won't fail under all circumstances if you *don't* close the mocks, but there are cases where it's necessary, so any generic test framework should make sure to `close()`.